# k-shortest (alternative) path algorithm, java implementations

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, mathematical-optimization, shortest-path

Could you recommend any java library which implements k-shortest algorithm -> searching for alternative ways, not the only shortest one in directed multigraph ?

I found only JGraphT but there is actually bug (which i submitted) but it will take a lot of time to fix it i guess, are there any other available implementations ? Except JGraphT i found only small one-man projects :/

OR would be hard to modify Disjktra shortest path alg to show alternative paths ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in `k`-shortest edge disjoint or node disjoint paths? For the first, look into min cost max flow algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 Possible Options:

Option 1. The `class KshortestPath` from [the MascOpt Package](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mascotte/mascopt/release/docs-1.2/mascoptLib-1.2/mascoptLib/algos/abstractalgos/KShortestPath.html) is a good option for a Java implementation of k-shortest paths.

Option 2. You can also try this from [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-paths/downloads/detail?name=KShortestPaths_Java_v2.3.zip)
This seems to be a one person's effort, but the good thing is that the algorithm is shared: Yen's Ranking - the details are here.(http://www.ohloh.net/p/k-shortest-paths)

**Note**: Finding the shortest-paths between all pairs of nodes in a given graph is a different problem. See this SO question on [Dijkstra vs. Floyd-Warshall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846836/the-best-shortest-path-algorithm).

Also note that `k-shortest paths` for rich graphs tend to be slight variations of the (Dijkstra) shortest path - alternative paths between vertices on the shortest-path with slightly higher costs.

I know the OP asked for Java implementations but if people have a choice and R is an option, then the `kBestShortestPaths` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kBestShortestPaths/kBestShortestPaths.pdf) from CRAN is a very good option as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just tried Option 2: Yen's algorithm and it worked wonders! Execution time for a graph with ~400 nodes ~1000 links went down from 3000 ms (for JGrapht's implementation) to 0.3 ms for Yen's algorithm implementation. Yeah, 3000 -> 0.3. It's not a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the k-shortest paths is related but not the exact same problem as alternative paths. Good alternative paths are more complicated. [Have a read](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/1806.php) where other similar approaches are outlined:

- k-Shortest Paths
- Pareto optimality
- Plateau method
- Penalty approach

The plateau method is a bit illustrated [here](http://www.camvit.com/camvit-technical-english/Camvit-Choice-Routing-Explanation-english.pdf).

If it is possible for you to read German then [this lecture is nice](http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/_media/teaching/sommer2012/routenplanung/vorlesung12.pdf):

- e.g. optimizing regarding time or distance => problem: interesting alternatives are missing
- dijunct paths => same problem
- k-shortest paths => problem: the real alternative is probably NOT under the first 1000 paths

Page 5

So intuition tells us: an alternative should have nearly identical distance or time. but should be significant different. so the first idea: find a path which minizes length AND similarity. Problem: there could be local detours.

Page 6

we introduce a 3rd criterion: *local optimumality*: every short subpath needs to be a shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a similar request before, but looking for all paths on StackOverflow. 
[Find all paths in a graph with DFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803143/find-all-paths-in-a-graph-with-dfs)

Hope this helps, it was answered but not with the exact solution, but more of a guide